# Romaji and Hiragana seem to disagree

Tags: rōmaji

I encountered `道路標識`  (`どうろひょしき`) during my studies today.  Google Translate shows romaji `dōrohyōji`.  However, based on the hiragana alone, I was expecting to see `dōrohyōshiki`.

Why is `しき` romanized as `ji` instead of `shiki`?  Are there different standards of romanization being used here?

Comment: Probably a bug. Put a space between 道路 and 標識 and Google shows "Dōro hyōshiki"

Comment: Keep in mind Google Translate is a fairly low quality resource.  You should expect it to make lots of mistakes and shouldn’t expect to learn Japanese from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different things, but very similar.
道路標識 dōrohyōshiki is road signs.
道路(路面)標示 dōrohyōji is road markings.

Google doesn't know the difference.